# Notification became junk with Clean Master app in Android

Tags: android, notifications

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I am doing push notification using Firebase. When I push from server, it shows notification in status bar in Android device. Pushing notification using Firebase is working fine.

I show notification like this in Android:

```
    private void showMatchesNotification(String message)
    {
        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        notification.setAutoCancel(true);
        notification.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.setTicker(message);
        notification.setContentTitle(getApplication().getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(MainActivity.FIELD_SELECTED_BOTTOM_TAB, MainActivity.BOTTOM_TAB_MATCHES);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(3,notification.build());
    }
```

The problem is when I show notification in Android, notification became junk in Clean Master app. Like below.

[image]

But when I tap on it, it is showing notifactions like this.

[image]

My question is, are notifications always marked as junk if Clean Master app is installed? Is there a way to push notification avoiding of becoming junks in Clean Master app? I want to show notification of my app in the status bar, and not in the junks. How can I do that?

Comment: Just a food for thought about Clean Master: http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/530007-concerned-about-clean-master-s-data-collection-privacy-practices-2.html http://androidforums.com/threads/cleaning-apps.984881/page-2#post-7186025

Comment: I am facing same issue. CM itself is JUNK app and its frustrating. Why does it treat notification from particular app as non-junk notification and rest of app as junk notification?

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the the 'junk notification" feature in CM. This is a feature you must have enabled in the first place, as it is not active on install. While  I use CM, I've never enabled the 'junk notification' feature (might also be known as 'quiet notification"), I prefer to control notifications via each individual app setting. Otherwise, I don't really find them to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you enable Junk notification in CleanMaster app, it will put the notifications to junk of other apps. Click on the settings button in Notification cleaner on top right and you can see all apps which are enabled or disabled for notification cleaner. You can uncheck your app to prevent Cleanmaster from putting your notification to junk.